# What are my options for C++ DLL to call a C# DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, idispatch

I have a C++ DLL that needs to call a function (pass a value, return a value) in a C# class library.

Is my only option to give the C# DLL a COM interface and call it from C++ with IDispatch?

Is this the best method?

Comment: Is there any way you can use managed C++ and avoid COM altogether?

Comment: Is this a C# app or a C++ app?

Comment: Got to wonder what JonSkeet has to say on this one...  :-)

Comment: It is a C++ DLL calling a C# DLL. The C++ is used by another app.

I can't alter the interface to the C++ DLL (and therefore managed C++ wrapper around it, is out of the question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of options available for you here

1. Use a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly as a bridge between the C++ and C# DLL
2. Use the a COM bridge by exposing several of the key C# types as COM objects.  This can then be accessed via the C++ code by normal COM semantics

Answer (score 1):

[This project](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) Creates dll exports for static methods in classes. You could then call a C# static method from unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that would work would be to call it though COM.  You can use [the Regasm tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(VS.71).aspx) to create the COM wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the *only* option.

You could also compile your C++ DLL as a managed DLL.

You could host your C# DLL as a service and remote into it.