# Wrapping C# code to be called from C++

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed, word-wrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are my options for C++ DLL to call a C# DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971645/what-are-my-options-for-c-dll-to-call-a-c-dll)

Okay so there is a load of material talking about how to wrap unmanaged code written in C++ or other languages and compiled to a DLL, and making a C# wrapping to make this unmanaged code something that can be called from C# directly.

I can't seem to find any material on calling managed code, from unmanaged code. That is, given a C# library, I'd like to wrap it such that I can call it's functions from C++. It that possible?

Comment: here's just one of the mahny hits from google: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736. Basically you use COM.

Comment: Definite duplicate of the dozens of related questions that pop up when you type in this question's title in the Ask Question form. =)

Comment: J. Steen, nearly all of those are talking about the reverse procedure.
stijn, a COM was not a good solution for me, and I suppose that would have been a good question for me to have found earlier, but all I saw was a sea of people asking the reverse question a million times.

Comment: Ah, my bad. It *is* usually the reverse, yes. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/unmanaged_to_managed.aspx) might be worth looking at.

Comment: Definitely worth looking at. This is like exactly what I was looking for, but now that I realize how much work I'm setting up for myself with the possibility of it not working, I think I'll do something else, but this is good for future reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to expose your component to COM interop: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx